# Compiling a module with f2py with an interface

Tags: fortran, f2py

I am trying to compile a fortran module with f2py. It is the following code

```
module my_log_mod

   implicit none

    interface my_log
        module procedure my_log_array
        module procedure my_log_vector
    end interface my_log

   private  ! hides items not listed on public statement 
   public :: my_log


contains

    subroutine my_log_array(a,res)
        double precision, dimension (:,:), intent (in) :: a
        double precision, dimension (:,:), intent (out) :: res

        where (a>1.0)
            res = log(a)
        else where
            res = 0.D0
        end where
    end subroutine  

    subroutine my_log_vector(a,res)
        double precision, dimension (:), intent (in) :: a
        double precision, dimension (:), intent (out) :: res

        where (a>1.0)
            res = log(a)
        else where
            res = 0.D0
        end where
    end subroutine  

end module my_log_mod
```

that I compile with the following command

```
f2py.py -c -m my_log_mod_comp my_log_mod.f90
```

and it results in the following error

```
C:\Users\weisshau\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf0apqa7s\src.win32-3.6\my_log_mod_comp-f2pywrappers2.f90:7:28:

       use my_log_mod, only : my_log_array
                            1
Error: Symbol 'my_log_array' referenced at (1) not found in module 'my_log_mod'
C:\Users\weisshau\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf0apqa7s\src.win32-3.6\my_log_mod_comp-f2pywrappers2.f90:18:28:

       use my_log_mod, only : my_log_vector
                            1
Error: Symbol 'my_log_vector' referenced at (1) not found in module 'my_log_mod'
```

I don't really know much about fortran and f2py, so I don't have any idea what is happening. If i use the module in pure fortran it works nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F2py appears to be creating another wrapper code which uses the subroutines in your module.

But it calls directly the subroutines `my_log_vector` and `my_log_array`. It seems f2py does not support `private`. I would delete the `private`.

Also be prepared that you won't be able to use the generic `my_log` in Python. This concept of generics is alien to Python. You may need to delete the generic interface if deleting `private` does not make it compilable. You should definitely delete the `public :: my_log`.

Unfortunately, f2py does not support all features of modern Fortran.

The code I tested:

```
module my_log_mod

   implicit none

    interface my_log
        module procedure my_log_array
        module procedure my_log_vector
    end interface my_log

contains

    subroutine my_log_array(a,res)
        double precision, dimension (:,:), intent (in) :: a
        double precision, dimension (:,:), intent (out) :: res

        where (a>1.0)
            res = log(a)
        else where
            res = 0.D0
        end where
    end subroutine  

    subroutine my_log_vector(a,res)
        double precision, dimension (:), intent (in) :: a
        double precision, dimension (:), intent (out) :: res

        where (a>1.0)
            res = log(a)
        else where
            res = 0.D0
        end where
    end subroutine  

end module my_log_mod
```

compilation:

```
f2py -c -m my_log_mod_comp my_log_mod.f90

...

Post-processing...
        Block: my_log_mod_comp
                        Block: my_log_mod
                                Block: my_log
                                Block: my_log_array
                                Block: my_log_vector
Post-processing (stage 2)...
        Block: my_log_mod_comp
                Block: unknown_interface
                        Block: my_log_mod
                                Block: my_log_array
                                Block: my_log_vector
Building modules...
        Building module "my_log_mod_comp"...
                Constructing F90 module support for "my_log_mod"...
                Creating wrapper for Fortran subroutine "my_log_array"
                      res = my_log_array(a)
                          res = my_log_array(a)
                Creating wrapper for Fortran subroutine "my_log_vector"("my_log_vector")...
                        Constructing wrapper function "my_log_mod.my_log_vector"...
                          res = my_log_vector(a)
        Wrote C/API module "my_log_mod_comp" to file "/tmp/tmp7e5v0u/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_log_mod_compmodule.c"
        Fortran 90 wrappers are saved to "/tmp/tmp7e5v0u/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_log_mod_comp-f2pywrappers2.f90"

...

gfortran:f90: /tmp/tmp7e5v0u/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_log_mod_comp-f2pywrappers2.f90
/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared /tmp/tmp7e5v0u/tmp/tmp7e5v0u/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_log_mod_compmodule.o /tmp/tmp7e5v0u/tmp/tmp7e5v0u/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.o /tmp/tmp7e5v0u/my_log_mod.o /tmp/tmp7e5v0u/tmp/tmp7e5v0u/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_log_mod_comp-f2pywrappers2.o -L/usr/lib64 -lpython2.7 -lgfortran -o ./my_log_mod_comp.so
Removing build directory /tmp/tmp7e5v0u
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried both of your suggestions but it does still not work. Maybe I should broaden my question to: "How do i write a fortran subroutine that takes arbitrary arrays as input and output and use it with f2py"

Comment: It does work on my computer. At least with the code you provided. Explain *it does not work*. This phrase does not tell anything. What do you mean?

Comment: *"How do i write a fortran subroutine that takes arbitrary arrays as input and output and use it with f2py"* You don't. That is the point I was making in my answer.

Comment: I tried deleting the two lines after the interface block and deleting the interface block all together but it always fails with the same error as in my question. To you second point: Ok that is good to know, but isn't that quite a huge shortcoming of f2py?

Comment: You can create a wrapper to these two in Python. Python uses duck typing and Fortran uses generics with specific subroutines. These two approaches are not compatible. One could imagine that f2py created this wrapper for you, but it is not what happens. I repeat from my answer: **Unfortunately, f2py does not support all features of modern Fortran.**

Comment: Regarding the code, it does compile after commenting he `public` and `private` on my computer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Could you include the code you used and the command in your answer? I would really like to understand why it does not work on my machine.